# PHP mysql error: "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"

Tags: php, mysql, select, stored-procedures

First of all let me say I have looked around and found similar posts like this but none of them are helping me so this is why I am asking you help.

Using PHP, I am trying to execute two SQL queries. First query does a `Select` statement with `INNER JOIN`, the other does a normal `select` statement.

Here is my code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS);

mysql_select_db(DBNAME);
$result = mysql_query("
      SELECT a.`role` AS 'role'
      FROM authme
      INNER JOIN a
      ON `authme`.`username` = `a`.`username`
      WHERE `authme`.`username` = 'vidhu';
", $conn); 
echo mysql_result($result, 0) . "<br />";

mysql_select_db(DBNAME);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `authme` WHERE `username` = 'vidhu'", $conn); 
echo mysql_result($result, 0) . "<br />";
```

So when I execute this page is what I get:

```
Admin   <--- Result from first query

Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in    C:\Apache24\htdocs\test.php on line 12  <---- second query
```

Executing both queries individually, works fine, but when both are combined I get that error. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time to read this!
Vidhu

Comment: You don't need to select the same db repeatedly - only when you really do need to change the default db.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2):

The `mysql_query` function will return boolean FALSE if it fails. You are using the result without checking if it failed, so you're passing that FALSE value instead of a proper result.

Comment: Not to mention he shouldn't be using `mysql_*` at all. But that's a story for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

when doing `mysql_query(query,connection)` you should always use the `or die(mysql_error());`

so it looks like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sometable") or die(mysql_error());
```

not only will it return false, it will stop at the point of error and echo out the exact error that you are getting with the MYSQL code.